# JSON field tag issue not taken into account during encoding

Tags: json, go

I have the following Go code

```
    type Version struct {
        Name string `json: "name"`
        Project   string `json: "project"`
        ProjectId int    `json: "projectId"`
    }

    b := new(bytes.Buffer)
    if err := json.NewEncoder(b).Encode(&Version{"foo", "bar", 42}); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return false
    }

    fmt.Printf("JSON %v", b)
```

The output is:

```
{"Name":"foo","Project":"bar","ProjectId": 42}
```

instead of:

```
{"name":"foo","project":"bar","projectId": 42}
```

Any thoughts why?

Thanks

Comment: It is probably spaces between tag name and tag value, try like this: `json:"name"`

Comment: btw `go vet` catches this error; probably a good idea to run `go vet` on save in your editor.

Comment: Thanks, that was it indeed. Great tip regarding go vet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your struct tags aren't proper so the parser isn't working as expected

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Version struct {
    Name      string `json:"name"`
    Project   string `json:"project"`
    ProjectId int    `json:"project_id"`
}

func main() {
    b := new(bytes.Buffer)
    if err := json.NewEncoder(b).Encode(&Version{"foo", "bar", 42}); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("JSON %v", b)
}
```

works as expected